# Laravel resource collection paginate override

Tags: laravel, api, response

I'm working on a Laravel app and I use Resource collection with pagination to return responses for my apis calls. I want to be able to set the number of results returned per page from the URL. For example, if the url is like:

```
xyz.com/api/users?perpage=10
```

I know I can simply pass this number to `->paginate(10)` but I want this to be dynamic for all my APIs. I think I have to override `paginate()` or maybe another method but I'm not sure. So instead of calling `->paginate(10)` I would call `->paginate($request)`. My question is what methodI should override that can keep the original behavior of paginate and I would add this functionality to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass perpage in the first argument of paginate function and have a default value if not provided.

```
User::paginate((int)$request->input('perpage', 15));
```

Comment: I know, but this doesn't help as  I want this to be automatic in all my APIs, that's why I'm trying to overrive paginate.

Comment: @mklomklo You want to override it without changing the current syntax and without touching the vendor folder and I guess without extending all models from a basic model ?